# How to change the size (resolution) of one pageview in Spotfire

Tags: business-intelligence, screen-resolution, spotfire, tibco

I saw a viz in the company's repository, and I wish to replicate one of the feature.
The viz is consist of several pages with an introductory page. The introductory page contained a lot of information with a scrollable canvas, while other detail page had a fixed-to-window way of presenting data, showing each segment in one screen without the overall scroll bar.

What I want to know is how to only make one or part of the pages in the dxp file able to enable the scroll bar (larger canvas height), while the rest having the fit-to screen way of displaying the viz. Any approach will be appreciated.

PS:
The Document Property→General→Visualization area size→Custom size method changes the canvas size of all visualization table. Which is not able to fulfill this feature, as this property changes the canvas size of all pages in the dxp file, which is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like they used a Text Area but it's hard to tell without seeing the document.

you can insert a Text Area the same way you do a visualization (via the toolbar or the main menu). you can then right click the Text Area to edit it either with the WYSIWYG editor or in raw HTML. Text Areas will show scrollbars to match the length of your content.